# How to name WebElements like div, b, span in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, naming-conventions

For example, frames and dropdown lists I name as `somethingFrame`, `somethingDropDown`. But what about `<div>`, `<b>`, `<span>` etc.?

Is there any standard in this regard (`somethingBold`, `somethingSpan`)?

Or just better leave it as it is (just `something`)?

```
  @FindBy(xpath = "//b[contains(text(), 'Something')]")
  private WebElement something?;
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the same convention as with the other web elements, something unique about it and the tag itself. If I'm aiming for a span containing something like username I'd use:

```
  @FindBy(xpath = "//span[@data-testid='loginUsernameLabel']")
  private WebElement loginUsernameLabelSpan
```

For something like the anchor tag, I'd use link instead b.c. it's more universally recognizable than anchor, but that's just a matter of preference.

```
  @FindBy(xpath = "//a[@data-testid='loginLink']")
  private WebElement loginLink
```

If you're working with a team or group of QAs discuss it together. Pick a convention and stick to it though. I've worked for companies that are super loose with naming convention and it can lead to code duplication and general confusion when someone new is trying to read through code and implement tests that they didn't personally help create the POM for.

Answer (score 0):

As per [*wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)):

> Naming convention is a set of rules for choosing the character
> sequence to be used for identifiers which denote variables, types,
> functions, and other entities in source code and documentation.
>
> Reasons for using a naming convention (as opposed to allowing
> programmers to choose any character sequence) include the following:
>
> - To reduce the effort needed to read and understand source code.
> - To enable code reviews to focus on issues more important than syntax and naming standards.
> - To enable code quality review tools to focus their reporting mainly on significant issues other than syntax and style preferences.

From a top level, there are two different naming convention practiced in *Python* and *Java*.

- *Python*: Python recommends *`UpperCamelCase`* for class names, *`CAPITALIZED_WITH_UNDERSCORES`* for constants, and *`lowercase_separated_by_underscores`* for other names.
- *Java*: In Java, naming conventions for identifiers have been established as follows:

  - Class names should be nouns in *`UpperCamelCase`*, with the first letter of every word capitalised.
  - Methods should be verbs in *`lowerCamelCase`* or a multi-word name that begins with a verb in lowercase; that is, with the first letter lowercase and the first letters of subsequent words in uppercase.
  - Local variables, instance variables, and class variables are also written in *`lowerCamelCase`*. Variable names should not start with underscore (`_`) or dollar sign (`$`) characters, even though both are allowed.
  - Constants should be written in uppercase characters separated by underscores. Constant names may also contain digits if appropriate, but not as the first character.

---

### This usecase

As per your usecase, to name the *logged in username in bold* you can use the following:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//b[contains(text(), 'scode')]")
private WebElement loggedUserHomepageBoldName;
```

To name the *label above username* you can use the following:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//b[contains(text(), 'scode')]//preceding::label[1]")
private WebElement loggedUserHomepageNameLabel;
```